# Parse variable inside string template with double curly braces in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I am looking for a library or pure javascript code that can inject a variable inside a string that contains the symbol `{{ variable }}`

My attempt is limited to only plain variable, not nested objects with arrays

```
const templateEn = 'A driver is asking for {{order.total.0}} {{ currency }} and says {{{{order.hello}}}}'
const templateFr = 'Un chauffeur demande {{order.total.0}} {{ currency }} et dit {{{{order.hello}}}}'

const payload = {
    order:{
        total:[456],
        hello: 'Hi!'
    },
    currency:'AUD',
}


const expectedFr = parseTemplate(templateFr, payload);
const expectedEn = parseTemplate(templateFr, payload);

assert(expectedFr === 'Un chauffeur demande 456 AUD et dit {{Hi!}}')
assert(expectedEn === 'A driver is asking for 456 AUD says {{Hi!}}')
```

## Edit

this was my attempt working only on plain object

```
var Strings = {
    create : (function() {
        var regexp = /{([^{]+)}/g;

        return function(str, o) {
            return str.replace(regexp, function(ignore, key){
                return (key = o[key]) == null ? '' : key;
            });
        }
    })()
};


function customPrototype (){
    String.prototype.create = function(o) {
        return Strings.create(this, o);
    }
    String.prototype.format = function(o) {
        return Strings.create(this, o);
    }
}
module.exports = customPrototype
```

Comment: maybe something like this (your need add dotprops), https://gist.github.com/lcherone/f7ef70406c7c84aeb7d64566afb63bb8

Comment: Can't you use Template-Strings like this: `string text ${expression} string text` with a backtick at beginning and end.

Comment: How about https://github.com/janl/mustache.js ?

Comment: @haim770 thank you for your suggestion. I tried mustache for the first time and it works for most cases but the lib is a bit confused when I put the 4 curly braces. it removes all curly braces by default

Comment: When we get with mustache is `const templateEn = 'A driver is asking for 456 AUD and says }'
const templateFr = 'Un chauffeur demande 456 AUD et dit }'`

Comment: You are setting an expectation (that replaceable values are surrounded by two sets of '{}') and then showing a case that violates that expectation. Rather than show what you want and then provide examples that violate your requirements, tell us what you want to happen (for all cases) and I'll be happy to provide a complete solution.